# Using MySQLi methods via child class

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I'm trying to make use of the MySQLi class, but don't want to have to write out the connection details each time. What I've been trying to do is make an extended class of `mysqli`, called `database` that will return a connection handler and eventually fail gracefully if no connection can be made (I've not done that yet).

But, the problem I've ran into is (and I apologise now if this is incredibly easy) I'm unable to use accesss the `mysqli` methods to prepare, bind and execute statements in my other classes after instantiating the child class `database` and passing it to the method that needs it.

Am I going down the right route? As MySQLi can be implemented OOP, I thought writing a whole new class just to use it when I can use the required methods in each class was sort of defeating the point of it?

Below is my `database` class that extends `mysqli`.

```
class database extends mysqli{

    //set connection variables
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $username = "username";
    private $password = "password";
    private $db_name = "db_name"; //database name

    public function connect(){
        $mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);

        if ($mysqli->connect_errno){//check if any connection error was encountered
            return false;
        } else {
            return $mysqli;
        }       
    }
}
```

And this is my registration class that will potentially be preparing statements, executing queries etc.

```
class registration{

private $email;
private $sec_email;
private $password;
private $sec_pass;
private $code;

function __construct($code, $email, $sec_email, $password, $sec_pass){
 //Sets all the vars above
}

public function check_vars(){//Check variables are set and valid.
 $mysqli = new database;
 if($mysqli){ 
  $code_check = $this->check_code($this->code, $mysqli);
  if($code_check == true){
   //Code checks out
  }
 }
}

private function check_code($code, $mysqli){
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `code` FROM `code_list` WHERE `code` = ? LIMIT 1")){
//return true
  }
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance and I apologise if there is an easy answer that I've overlooked.

`UPDATE`

Since reading the answer left by @Your Common Sense, I've done the following:

index.php

```
require_once('config.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass'], $db['dbname']);
$display = new dispaly($mysqli);
//Display methods...
```

config.php

```
$db = array('host' => 'host', 'user' => 'user', 'pass' => 'pass', 'dbname' => 'dbname')
require_once('lib/other.classes.php');
//More classes
```

Mainly wanted to add that since this answer was supplied, I've started to use Dependency Injection for a lot of other objects too, instead of instantiating new ones everytime I needed them.

Thank @Your Common Sense, and @Bill Karwin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I going down the right route?

## Definitely no

First, you don't need no dedicated database class to gracefully fail. It have to be done centralized in the application-wide error handler for ALL the errors at once, not for the every API separately.

Second, your idea of creating a new database class instance in every class is just terrible.

So, here is the right direction:

1. Create just plain and raw mysqli class instance. **Once.**
2. Pass it *as argument* in other classes constructors.

So here goes your application class

```
class registration()
{
    private $db;
    public $email;
    public $sec_email;
    public $password;
    public $sec_pass;
    public $code;

    function __construct($mysqli)
    {
        $this->db = $mysqli;
    }

    public function init($code, $email, $sec_email, $password, $sec_pass)
    {
        $code_check = $this->check_code($this->code);
    }

    private function check_code($code)
    {
        $sql  = "SELECT `code` FROM `code_list` WHERE `code` = ? LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    }
}
```

In the future, then you make yourself familiar with mysqli and its drawbacks, consider writing (or adopting) mysqli wrapper class. A *sensible* one.

Comment: Ah brilliant, so instead of writing a new class, use the MySQLi class as is, instantiate in my index.php, and then use Dependency Injection to pass the MySQLi object to objects that need it?

Answer (score 0):

Several suggestions:

- I would design the database class to read the parameters from a config file instead of from private variables.

  You could write a PHP file that does nothing but declare an array of
  connection options, then include() that file. Alternatively, write
  the config file as a kind of "ini" format file, and use
  http://php.net/parse_ini_file to parse it.
- You check for $mysqli->connect_errno, but you neither log nor output the error message. This will make it harder to find out *why* a connection fails.
- The $mysqli variable is local to your check_vars() method. It will not be accessible outside that method.

  ```
  $mysqli = new database;
  ```

  You should make it a class variable:

  ```
  $this->mysqli = new database;
  ```
- This is wrong:

  ```
  ...WHERE `code` = `?`
  ```

  Parameter placeholders must not go inside any type of quotes. Just use this:

  ```
  ...WHERE `code` = ?
  ```
- I kind of agree with @YourCommonSense, that there's little benefit to *extending* the mysqli class. You could simply design a singleton class:

  ```
  class Database
  {
    static $db = null;
    private __construct() { }
    public static getConnection()
    {
      if (!self::$db) {
        // read connect options from a config file
        self::$db = new mysqli(...);
        // check for errors, etc.
      }
      return self::$db;
    }
  }
  ```

  Then anytime you need a database, you can call the static method `Database::getConnection()` with the assurance that it will create a new connection only once per request.

Comment: When you say config file, do you mean using an `include_once` with a set of global variables in that config file? Yea, the `connect_errno` is a work in progress, I need to go back to that. So can I not pass the `$mysqli` object to check_code, or is just better practice to make `$mysqli` accessible throughout the class, instead of just the method? Thanks again @bill !